# Why is my initial window larger than set in storyboard?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, storyboard, nswindow

In my Objective-C/Cocoa app, the initial window is always much wider than designed in the storyboard. In the storyboard editor, the window has a size of 480x270, and so does the view. The view in turn has just a table view, a popup menu and a label on it, all nicely equipped with constraints which look correct. It does not have a min/max content size set, and there is no code which could affect the window size. The content of the table view and popup menu are all much shorter that their controls, so they should not "grow" my window either.

Yet when the app launches, the window is approx. 1000-1200 pixels wide. The height is as defined in the storyboard. If I close the window and create a new one, is is too wide again - even if I resized the window manually to something else before closing it. So it does not appear to save the window size somewhere.

I have no Autosave name on the window, and unchecking the "Restorable" checkbox did not change anything either.

What else could cause the window to be much wider than intended?

**Edit**: This is the view layout:
[image: View Layout]

Comment: I am not sure how it works in OSX, but do you have  height and width constraints for the view?

Comment: No, the view has no absolute w/h constraints - but edge constraints to the table view, label and popup of course, so that they resize together with the view/window.

Answer (score -1):

Put all your content in the Vertical Stack control element and assign the constraint to 0 to all four sides and put all your controls inside this new Vertical stack control.

Also please check the label has proper constraint...as most of the time this label is the main culprit.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but why would I have t do that? It's not a stack-based layout, I'm just using constraints. The label is to the left of the popup, has leading/trailing/baseline constraints. But the label is not growing, the popup menu is (when I resize the window), and that is correct.

Comment: What is the vertical stack?